# Is Japanese に related to the Chinese character 仁?

Tags: kanji, etymology, hiragana, chinese, language-evolution

Is Japanese に (pronounced as "ni") related to the [Chinese character 仁 (pronounced as "ren" in Chinese mandarin)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren_(Confucianism))?

Does the に have the root from the Chinese character 仁?

They both sound similar and look very similar.

Comment: I just found this correspondence: https://www.hana300.com/aakana.html maybe they should be more well-known.

Comment: Note that 仁 was likely pronounced with a nasal initial (n(j)in) in Old/Middle Chinese.

Comment: It's worth noting that 仁 is still used in Japanese too.  [Notable example](https://store.steampowered.com/app/485510/Nioh_Complete_Edition___Complete_Edition/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the *kana* に is derived from the Chinese character ([漢字]{かんじ}, *kanji*) 仁.  See also [the English Wiktionary page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%AB#Japanese) and [the Japanese Wikipedia page](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%AB), among other references.

All *kana* derived from *kanji*.  In fact, the word *kana* originally meant something like "provisional / borrowed + name / label" (from older *kari na* or 仮り名), in reference to the way that the kanji were *borrowed* and then used as *labels* for the sounds of Japanese.

Comment: I just found this correspondence: https://www.hana300.com/aakana.html maybe they should be more well-known.

Comment: @wonderich: For what it's worth, I've found that the English Wiktionary has good coverage of the individual kana and their origins, with explanations written in English.  _(Full disclosure: I'm an on-again-off-again editor and admin there, although I don't think I've edited any of the entries about the kana origins.)_

Comment: @wonderich I think this is one of those things that isn't taught directly, since it's not actually relevant to immediately understanding modern Japanese, but most people find out when they reach about intermediate level.

Comment: @wonderich, I'd also forgotten that [the "History" section for the Wikipedia article on "Hiragana"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiragana#History) includes a table showing the original kanji, cursive forms, and modern kana derivations.  That provides a good quick overview.